# How to fix the unnecessary white space on top?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to the react native. I have started to build the login page. But on top it is showing the white space. I checked in both Android and IOS. Both having the spaces. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Please add some code what you have done.

Comment: Please share your findings as well as the code

Comment: Make sure You didn't add empty `<Text>` or `<View>` with `height` style